# Android Material Dropdown: Selected dropdown item is presented like toString instead of defined View

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I'm trying to use android material styling for components `TextInputLayout` with `AutoCompleteTextView`. I want the selected item is presented in the same way as in the dropdown list: image and text.

I tried with `Spinner` within `TextInputLayout` and Spinner and `AutoCompleteTextView` without `TextInputLayout`. All the combinations work but the first does not (material styling isn't applied for these combinations).

The selected item is presented as toString of the object that I use for my custom adapter.

What am I doing wrong?

*P.S.: I'm using SVG drawables for the images.*

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/language_from"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="from"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/language_to"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/language_from_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/language_to"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:hint="to"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/language_from">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/language_to_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:hint="label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/language_to">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/searchInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="412dp"
        android:layout_height="531dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchInputLayout">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val languageList = createLanguages()
        val adapter = LanguageAdapter(this, languageList)

        val languageFromDropdown = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.language_from_view)
        val languageToDropdown = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.language_to_view)

        languageFromDropdown.setAdapter(adapter)
        languageToDropdown.setAdapter(adapter)
    }

    private fun createLanguages(): List<LanguageDropdownItem>
            = listOf(LanguageDropdownItem(Language.POLISH, R.drawable.ic_polish_flag),
                     LanguageDropdownItem(Language.ENGLISH, R.drawable.ic_english_flag),
                     LanguageDropdownItem(Language.GERMAN, R.drawable.ic_german_flag),
                     LanguageDropdownItem(Language.FRENCH, R.drawable.ic_french_flag),
                     LanguageDropdownItem(Language.ITALIAN, R.drawable.ic_italian_flag),
                     LanguageDropdownItem(Language.SWISS, R.drawable.ic_swiss_flag))

}
```

**language_dropdown_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_english_flag" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/language_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/flag_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**LanguageDropdownItem.kt**

```
data class LanguageDropdownItem(val language: Language, val drawableFlag: Int)
```

**LanguageAdapter.kt**

```
class LanguageAdapter(val mContext: Context,
                      val mLanguages: List<LanguageDropdownItem>)
    : ArrayAdapter<LanguageDropdownItem>(mContext, 0, mLanguages) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var dropdownItemView = convertView

        if (dropdownItemView == null)
            dropdownItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                                .inflate(R.layout.language_dropdown_item, parent,false)

        val language = mLanguages[position]

        val flagImage: ImageView = dropdownItemView!!.findViewById(R.id.flag_image)
        flagImage.setImageResource(language.drawableFlag)

        val langTextView: TextView = dropdownItemView.findViewById(R.id.language_name)
        langTextView.text = language.language.name

        return dropdownItemView
    }
}
```

And Language is enum class with language names.

[image: screenshot of my dropdown and selected result]

Comment: It's because `AutoCompleteTextView` sets the value of the dropdown to your data class' `toString` return value. Refs: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/b6f19d115c8c354da9f07bfa820d93fe6047094b/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java#L237-L247, https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java;l=971-981;bpv=0, https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Filter.java;l=165-176;bpv=0

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1007

Answer (score 3):

If you would override toString() function of your LanguageDropdownItem, you will achieve what you want...

Note: I have solved my problem like this.

```
data class LanguageDropdownItem(val language: Language, val drawableFlag: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in Kotlin by overriding tostring in your data class

```
data class LanguageDropdownItem(
  val language: Language,
  val drawableFlag: Int
){
    override fun toString(): String {
        //return "$language"
    }
}
```